# Publicaciones de baja calidad - pregunta con votos, pero de baja calidad

Tags: discusión, auditorías-de-revisión

Revisando las publicaciones de baja calidad, me encontré con esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/217662/disparadores-o-procedimiento-almacenado-mysql).

Durante la revisión, decidí votar para cerrarla *(ya que no considero que la pregunta aporte información útil)*.

Sin embargo, obtuve este mensaje:

[image: Pregunta de baja calidad]

Realmente me pregunto: ¿esta es una pregunta que realmente ofrece información útil?

¿Alguien ha tenido una experiencia similar? y, de ser así ¿cómo debería reaccionar el usuario que revisa este tipo de publicaciones?

---

**NOTA:** Esta pregunta es mas de tipo inquietud que una queja contra el OP o el sistema de Stack Overflow en Español.

Comment: En mi opinión, este es un fallo de la auditoria. Se sabe que no son perfectas y en este caso el problema es que algunas personas le dieron un voto positivo, cuando la pregunta, si bien no es del todo mala, en su estado actual debiera ser cerrada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La pregunta es **mala**. Y, a mi juicio, el motivo es `no está claro lo que se pregunta`:

> Cuando registro un contrato se ocupa una bodega que esta identificada por su id. El problema viene cuando registro 2 contratos en una bodega al mismo tiempo. quiero evitar esto y me sugirieron usar o disparadores o procedimientos almacenados. Quisiera saber su **opinión** y si me pueden dar una idea de como seria.

¿ Sobre que está preguntando **concretamente** ? ¿ Pide ideas generales para su problema ? ¿ Pide opiniones sobre una posible solución usando *disparadores* ? ¿ Pide sugerencias acerca de implementarlo mediante procedimientos almacenados ?

El resto de la pregunta no nos aclara mucho: solo muestra el diseño de las tablas.

Cualquiera de los 3 casos nos lleva a otro punto: `basada en opiniones`. Pero solo es posible llegar a esa conclusión cuando sabemos **exactamente** qué está preguntando.

Es similar a encontrarnos una pregunta escrita **en otro idioma**; los que puedan leer el idioma en cuestión podrían votarla, quizás, por un motivo mas concreto. Pero solo es posible **después** de leerla, así que el motivo correcto sería `no relacionado`.

¿ Porqué tiene 3 votos positivos ? Pues porque hay al menos 3 usuarios que no comparten mi opinión :-)

Como efecto secundario de ese último párrafo, está el que tú te has encontrado: si se usa para *auditar* ... pues eso, que tú has *suspendido* la auditoria ... igual que hubiera *suspendido* yo :-(

Answer (score -1):

La he revisado y es una pregunta interesante, por lo siguiente:

- ofrece un contexto de lo que necesita hacer
- aporta el código que oriente sobre la estructura de sus tablas

Lo que tiene de malo:

- Pide opiniones por lo cual se pudiera considerar para algunos como cierre
- No muestra su duda orientada a `triggers` por ejemplo

Lo que se le puede sugerir es que elimine la petición de opiniones y que muestre el código que ha tratado para resolver su problema

Vamos no es una pregunta mala del todo pero le falta mejorar la redacción y orientación de la misma